# How to make a binance futures order with ccxt in python?

Tags: python, ccxt

How can I place a market order in ccxt for binance futures?
Trading on binance futures with ccxt is already implemented

```
https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/pull/5907
```

In this post they suggest to use this line of code:

```
let binance_futures = new ccxt.binance({ options: { defaultMarket: 'futures' } })
```

The above line was written in JavaScript. How would the equivalent line in python look like?
Like this I get an error:

```
binance_futures = ccxt.binance({ 'option': { defaultMarket: 'futures' } })
NameError: name 'defaultMarket' is not defined
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The correct answer is that `'defaultType'` (instead of `defaultMarket`) must be in quotes, but also the value must be `'future'` (not `'futures'`)

```
import ccxt
print('CCXT version:', ccxt.__version__)  # requires CCXT version > 1.20.31
exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    'secret': 'YOUR_API_SECRET',
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',  # ←-------------- quotes and 'future'
    },
})

exchange.load_markets()

# exchange.verbose = True  # uncomment this line if it doesn't work

# your code here...
```

Comment: Could you also provide an example for a market buy and a market sell order on binance futures? How to set the leverage?

Comment: @eetiaro you can find some examples here: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/tree/master/examples/py let us know if that does not help

Comment: Note that this is no longer the recommended way. See my answer below.

Comment: Where it is in documentation ? can you please share me the link ?

Answer (score 6):

Put **quotes** around `defaultMarket`:

```
binance_futures = ccxt.binance({ 'option': { 'defaultMarket': 'futures' } })
```

Comment: With quotes I get no error anymore, but it still doesn't trades on the futures account. Orders are placed on the normal exchange instead. Any ideas?

Comment: @eetiaro it is `'future'`, not `'futures'`: `binance_futures = ccxt.binance({ 'option': { 'defaultMarket': 'future' } })`

Comment: Also answered here: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/6273#issuecomment-565563176

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for Binance's COIN-M futures (eg. for cash-futures basis trading), you need to [use the `delivery` option instead](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/00fb5389da706c0acc3bb0892ffa211ac535bd3b/python/ccxt/binance.py#L857):

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd

binance = ccxt.binance()
binance.options = {'defaultType': 'delivery', 'adjustForTimeDifference': True}

securities = pd.DataFrame(binance.load_markets()).transpose()
securities
```

dated futures as expected:

[image: Dated Futures]

Please note that the above snippet returns the dated futures as expected. However, the alternative one-line solution shown below **DOES NOT** (it seems to be defaulting to spot markets):

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd

binance = ccxt.binance({'option': {'defaultType': 'delivery', 'adjustForTimeDifference': True}})

securities = pd.DataFrame(binance.load_markets()).transpose()
securities
```

returns spot markets:

[image: Spot Markets]

Answer (score 3):

The new recommended way to create the `exchange` object is:

```
exchange = ccxt.binanceusdm({
    'apiKey': ...,
    'secret': ...,
})
```

This has been comfirmed by the project maintainer (@kroitor) on Discord.

The old way (which at time of writing still works) was:

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': ...,
    'secret': ...,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',
    },
})
```

Example code in the repo has not yet been updated (also confirmed).

Comment: The latest ccxt document shows nothing when you search `defaultType`. The ccxt **official document really really sucks**, every exchange category their API endpoint by Spot/Margin, Futures, Linear/Inverse, the ccxt is Unified API, Implicit API, bla bla,,, nobody understand what's that about.

Comment: Fortunately they have an active Discord (you can even connect with the lead dev).

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate the binance exchange and tweak its `options` property to `{'defaultType': 'future'}`

```
import ccxt

exchange_id = 'binance'
exchange_class = getattr(ccxt, exchange_id)
exchange = exchange_class({
    'apiKey': 'your-public-api-key',
    'secret': 'your-api-secret',
    'timeout': 30000,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

exchange.options = {'defaultType': 'future'}
markets = exchange.load_markets()  # Load the futures markets

for market in markets: 
    print(market)                # check for the symbol you want to trade here

# The rest of your code goes here
```

Comment: This is incorrect and dangerous. By setting `.options` you are erasing the existing `.options` dict. `exchange.options['defaultType'] = 'future'` is safe, as it only APPENDS to the dict.